# Can I run two versions of XAMPP (not at once) on Windows?

Tags: xampp

I am currently running a 5.x version of XAMPP on a Windows 10 box, which has been working really well.

However I think it is time I look at upgrading to version 7.x to test my sites before I get my production VPS server to run php 7 etc

Can I install the new version in a separate directory (e.g. xampp7) and choose what xampp to run as needed via its control panel?  Will each install know what version of php etc to load and use while that version is operating?

I have not tested this yet, I didn't want to risk stuffing up my existing install :)

Cheers

Comment: Yes you can run, just take care of ports for php and mysql for the two different installs.